# Drawing an Edge (Line) Between Two Nodes ( Circles)

Tags: java, geometry, 2d, drawing, p5.js

I am working on a dependancy graph that consists of multiple nodes and multiple directed edges from one node to another in the graph.

I am trying to draw a visualation of the graph by adding n number of nodes as circles and edges between those nodes as a line.

I a using Graphics library of Java along with JPanel and Jframe.

This is currently the code I have made:

```
public class LoopUnrolling extends JPanel{


static int length = 5;
static String graph[][] = new String[length][length];


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Random random = new Random();

    int x1 = random.nextInt(500);
    int y1 = random.nextInt(100);

    int x2 = random.nextInt(500);
    int y2 = random.nextInt(100);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(x1,y1,30,40);
    g.drawOval(x2,y2,30,40);
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);



}
public static void main(String[] args) {

         LoopUnrolling paintObject = new LoopUnrolling();
         JFrame jf = new JFrame();
         jf.setTitle("Dependancy Graph");
         jf.setSize(600,400);
         jf.setVisible(true);
         jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         jf.add(paintObject);
        }


 }
```

I was able to draw two circles and a line but **the problem**  I am getting is connecting those two circles with an edge.

I have drawn each node at a random place on the canvas and want to add a Line  between those two nodes. 
The line has Point1(x1,y1) and Point2(x2,y2). These points should be the points on two different Node's(Circles) outline

Comment: What is LoopUnrolling and what is you class extending? Please provide your full code and not just a small incorrect snippet.

Comment: LoopUnrolling is basically the name of the project.

Comment: No its a class you are using and adding to the JFrame. What is the purpose of that class?

Comment: Updated the code.

Comment: What exactly do you want to connect? The circle or the center of the ovales?

Comment: A point on the outline of circle1 and a point on the outline of circle2 with a line

Comment: Ah okay I see. Your problem is, that your coordinates are defining the upper left corner of a square around your ovale. That means you can't use them to draw a line.
Your problem is more a mathematic problem then an java problem.

Comment: Yes, is there any loop around to it? Maybe using a different shape that ends up as an oval or circle.

Comment: You can find the center of oval by knowing its height and width. You can hide line ends by drawing it behind opaque ovals. You dont need any math unless you want to have some fancy arrows on line ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ellipses with centers

```
 cx1 = x1 + w1/2, cy1 = y1 + h1/2 
 and 
 cx2 = x2 + w2/2, cy2 = y2 + h2/2
```

where wxx and hxx are width and height of ellipse (third and fourth parameters of `drawOval`)

Get difference vector

```
 dx = cx2 - cx1
 dy = cy2 - cy1
```

Normalize it

```
 len  = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
 dx = dx / len
 dy = dy / len
```

Now calculate points at circumference

```
 r1 = 0.5 * w1 * h1 / sqrt(w1*w1*dy*dy+h1*h1*dx*dx)
 px1 = cx1 + r1 * dx
 py1 = cy1 + r1 * dy

 r2 = 0.5 * w2 * h2 / sqrt(w2*w2*dy*dy+h2*h2*dx*dx)
 px2 = cx2 - r2 * dx
 py2 = cy2 - r2 * dy
```

And draw line segment `(px1,py1)-(px2,py2)`

Sample [Delphi implementation](https://ideone.com/cDyEI2) and result:
[image]

Comment: What is r1 and r2?

Comment: Radiuses of circles. But you have ellipses with two semiaxes, so solution should be modified

Comment: An error was corrected, approach is checked now (0.5 coeff added)

Comment: I am very thankful for your detailed explanation. Now the code works perfectly, thanks a lot!